# Generating 2-dimensional sample dataset from a mixture Guassian distribution

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, dataset

I wanted to generate a 2-dimensional sample dataset. I copied the code stated in this  [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70855/generating-random-variables-from-a-mixture-of-normal-distributions)  and doubled it to generate vectors X,Y to scatter them as 2-dimensional dataset as the following. But the result was not favourable. In fact I wanted something like the picture below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

mu = [1,4]
sigma = [2, 1]
p_i = [0.3, 0.7]
n = 1000

x = []
y=[]
for i in range(n):
    z_i = np.argmax(np.random.multinomial(1, p_i)) #np.random.multinomial(1,[0.3,0.5,0.2]) returns the result of an experiment
    #of rolling a dice. the result is as this: [1,0,0]. this means that the side one occurs in the experiment and the others 
    #not. the goal is choosing mu[i] in a random way
    x_i = np.random.normal(mu[z_i], sigma[z_i])
    x.append(x_i)

    
mu = [3,6]
sigma = [1, 2]
p_i = [0.6, 0.4]    

for i in range(n):
    z_i = np.argmax(np.random.multinomial(1, p_i)) #np.random.multinomial(1,[0.3,0.5,0.2]) returns the result of an experiment
    #of rolling a dice. the result is as this: [1,0,0]. this means that the side one occurs in the experiment and the others 
    #not. the goal is choosing mu[i] in a random way
    y_i = np.random.normal(mu[z_i], sigma[z_i])
    y.append(y_i)

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

`
[image]

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you're trying to plot is data sampled from 2 distinct 2D gaussians. Here is code that can plot mock data that looks like this. Feel free to adjust the mean and covariance matrix to suit your needs.

```py
from numpy.random import multivariate_normal

# First 2D gaussian:
mu = [1, 3]
cov = [[0.07, 0],[0, 1.8]]
x, y = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu, cov, 200).T

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.scatter(x, y, s=5, color='blue')
ax = plt.gca()

# Second 2D gaussian:
mu = [2, 1]
cov = [[0.8, -0.4],[-0.4, 0.5]]
x, y = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu, cov, 200).T
plt.scatter(x, y, s=5, color='red')

plt.xlim([-2, 8])
plt.ylim([-6, 10]);
```

This produces something like the plot below (different colors so you can see the pattern):

[image]

Comment: Thank you TC. Yes, it is exactly what I meant.

Comment: Dear TC, does this numpy method sample by Monte-Carlo simulations?